# How to unit test function that references CookieManager?

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric, android-unit-testing, android-cookiemanager

The application in question has a `logout` function that among other things, performs a call to `CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)`:

```
fun logout(...) {                                                                           
    showLoader(true)                                                          
                                                                                                                                                    
    msgRepo.unregisterSendBirdHandlersAndPushToken(                           
        onSuccess = {                                                         
            clearUserData(...)
            // ...                                       
            onLogout()                                                        
        },                                                                    
        onFailure = {                                                          
            clearUserData(...)
            // ...                                       
            onLogout()                                                        
        }                                                                     
    )                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                              
/**                                                                           
 * Helper to clear user data before logging user out                          
 */                                                                           
private fun clearUserData(...) {                                                                           
    // ...                                            
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
}
```

Two tests reference the aforementioned `logout` function. They both are quite similar and look a bit like this:

```
@Test                                                              
fun `verify logout with success`() {                               
    // .. Other code                                                             
    HardLogoutHelper.logout(...)                                                              
    // ...                            
}
```

The tests fail with the following error message:

> 'void android.webkit.CookieManager.removeAllCookies(android.webkit.ValueCallback)'
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void android.webkit.CookieManager.removeAllCookies(android.webkit.ValueCallback)'
> at com.example.helpers.HardLogoutHelper.clearUserData(HardLogoutHelper.kt:86)

I've tried running the test with Roboelectric via `@RunWith(RoboelectricTestRunner::class)` and I have have tried creating a custom Roboelectric Shadow for the `CookieManager` class. The issue seems to persist even when using Roboelectric.

Why is the previously mentioned error message being thrown, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Perhaps this class should not be referencing `CookieManager` directly. Instead, have it work with some custom interface. In production, you would have your dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.) supply an implementation of the interface that uses `CookieManager`. In a unit test, your test code would supply an implementation of the interface that is a fake or other type of test double.

Comment: The `logout` function is actually not in a traditional class but in a Kotlin `object` called `object HardLogoutHelper`. The `HardLogoutHelper.logout` function could certainly be rewritten to take a `CookieManager` argument, but then every place where `logout` is invoked would require a `CookieManager` instance.

Comment: "but then every place where logout is invoked would require a CookieManager instance"' -- I recommend that you look into using dependency inversion frameworks (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.).

Comment: The app does use Dagger. I simply don't want to pass along a dependency (i.e. provide a `CookieManager` instance to every place that may eventually call `HardLogoutHelper.logout`) through so many channels if there is a simpler solution for fixing the test.

Comment: If you inject `HardLogoutHelper`, you do not need to also inject a `CookieManager` -- Dagger can supply the `CookieManager` to `HardLogoutHelper`.